# Function arguments type error (unbounded constructor, no constructor) in ocaml

Tags: types, constructor, arguments, ocaml

I want to make a function which acts like this:

```
('a, 'a) >>>> ('a list, 'a list) >>>> ('a list, 'a list)
```

For example,

```
append_list (1, 2) ([10, 3], []) >>>> ([1, 10, 3], [2])
```

I got two errors

**Error1**

> let append_list ( a, b ) ( A, B ) =
>               ( a::A, b::B );;
>       Error: Unbound constructor A

**Error2**

> let append_list ( a, b ) ( (A : 'a list), (B : 'a list) ) =
>               ( a::A, b::B );;
>       Error: The variant type list has no constructor A

How can I make the function correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to the problem, it was a nonsense.

```
A, B
```

can't be used as name of variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
let append_list  (a,b)  (l1,l2)= (a::l1,b::l2) ;;
  Or
let append_list  ((a:'a),(b:'b))  ((l1:'a list),(l2:'b list))= (a::l1,b::l2) ;;
```

Test :

```
# append_list (1,2) ([10;3],[]);;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 10; 3], [2])

# append_list (1,'2') ([10;3],['4']);;
- : int list * char list = ([1; 10; 3], ['2'; '4'])
```